# How to make the Gnome Terminal transparent

Tags: gnome-terminal, configuration, customization, transparency

I have been having to use the Xfce 4 Terminal because I want to have a see through background, and I couldn't get it working in the Gnome Terminal, but as there are some disadvantages of using the Xfce 4 Terminal over the Gnome one, I was wondering if there is in fact a way to make the Gnome Terminal transparent?

People have previously told me to go to the preferences section, then to the background tab, and change the transparency settings there, but I am unable to find the background section.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
gnome-terminal:
  Installed: 3.14.2-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 3.14.2-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 3.14.2-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To activate and change transparency settings in `gnome-terminal` go `Edit > Profile preferences`, and then go to the `Colours` tab. You can tick the `Use transparent background` box to activate transparency and slide the slider in order to change the level of transparency:

[image]

Comment: To clarify: The upstream version *does not* support transparency. This is a feature patched in.